# How can I include dependencies from brew in a MacOS X python wheel?

Tags: python, macos, machine-learning, compilation, caffe

I built an application, Caffe, on Mac OS X. It has many dependencies in `brew`, a common package manager, and the build artifact is an importable Python module.

I believe I can package this module as a wheel, a module package of sorts. But I also want to ship all the dependencies. You can see the main binary dependencies here:

```
$ otool -L /Users/bberman/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/caffe/_caffe.so

/Users/bberman/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/caffe/_caffe.so:
    python/caffe/_caffe.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /Users/bberman/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/caffe/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3 (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
    @rpath/libcudart.7.5.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 7.5.27)
    @rpath/libcublas.7.5.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 7.5.27)
    @rpath/libcurand.7.5.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 7.5.27)
    /usr/local/opt/glog/lib/libglog.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/gflags/lib/libgflags.2.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.1.2)
    /usr/local/opt/protobuf/lib/libprotobuf.9.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.1.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost159/lib/libboost_system.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/boost159/lib/libboost_filesystem.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
    /usr/local/opt/hdf5/lib/libhdf5_hl.10.dylib (compatibility version 11.0.0, current version 11.2.0)
    /usr/local/opt/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.10.dylib (compatibility version 12.0.0, current version 12.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/leveldb/lib/libleveldb.1.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/snappy/lib/libsnappy.1.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/lmdb/lib/liblmdb.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_core.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.13)
    /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.13)
    /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_imgproc.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.13)
    /usr/local/opt/boost159/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libcudnn.5.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 5.1.3)
    /usr/local/opt/boost-python159/lib/libboost_python.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.10)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
```

You can check out those build steps here: https://gist.github.com/doctorpangloss/f8463bddce2a91b949639522ea1dcbe4 .

Caffee is a complex library and it's very helpful to use it through the Python module. How could I ship all these pieces in a wheel?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a standalone executable (out of python project) you might want to use [py2app](http://undefined.org/python/#py2app).

[Here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DistributionUtilities) you can find the documentation for all the Executable Applications
NOTE: py2exe is the same thing for windows

I might misunderstood your question, if so I would like to know :)

Comment: I updated the question to be a lot better and clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Armitage.apk's answer, using py2app an example of how you can actually convert python file to standalone application, this tutorial is great:
https://www.metachris.com/2015/11/create-standalone-mac-os-x-applications-with-python-and-py2app/

Comment: I updated the question to be a lot better and clearer.